# Reading from a file and storing it in a array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a txt file which contains 3 columns, i want to store these values in a 1-D array such that values from column 2 & 3 are only stored, not 1.

Here's a thought:

```
int main()

{

 double x1=[n];
 double y1= [n];

    std::ifstream fin ("1.txt",std::ifstream::in);

    i=1;
    while(!fin.eof())
    {
        fin>>i>>x1[i]>>y1[1];
        i++
    }
```

It appears  it isn't working? Any thought where I am wrong and how to improve this?

how can i store data in the form of 1-D array from a file which has 3 columns and i need to use just column 2 and 3. I am so confused.

PS- The full code is very long, it is just the beggining of the code,

Thanks !!

Comment: `double x1=[n];` ? `double x1[n]`?

Comment: it seems you read i from 1.txt, and then i++, doesn't make sense at all

Comment: ok.. the 1st column contains sl no as 1,2,3...n, i just need to use the 2nd and the 3rd one and store it as 2 arrays.. !! I think i++ means to keep incrementing by +1. ?

Comment: You already read i from the file, why do you need to increase it.

Comment: okay.. point taken.. !! now is this correct.. ? will it just take values from 2nd nd 3rd column and store it?

Comment: You can refer to may answer for details

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains too many mistakes...

If the first column is index.

```
double x1[n];
double y1[n];

std::ifstream fin ("1.txt",std::ifstream::in);

while(!fin.eof())
{
    int i;
    fin >> i;
    fin >> x1[i] >> y1[i];
}
```

Comment: okay.. but can you tell me how would it get to take 2nd and 3rd column if you do this? I dont get it?

Comment: sorry it was a typo..here something i tried an i got something-   `std::ifstream fin ("1.txt",std::ifstream::in);
int i=0;
while(!fin.eof())
{   double x1[n];
    double y1[n];
 
       fin >>i>> x1[i] >> y1[i];
i++ }`

Comment: this one should work, in my opinion. can you please paste a code snippet that can compile and run, and reproduce your problem.